# Max number of Salesforce Beta versions of managed packages

Tags: salesforce, package, limit, managed, beta

Is there a limit to the number of Beta versions we can create for a managed packaged for an AppExchange App?

Comment: I've never seen an enforced limit. Especially with respect to full releases (I'm aware your question is specifically about Beta versions). There probably is an upper limit enforced by the [Ids](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1653/what-are-salesforce-ids-composed-of) that represent the package.